# Check adjacency in 2d array C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game on unity 3D 4.7.2f where I have a grid of items that I can "connect" by touching them. If there's 3 or more chosen they disappear, if you have played Best Fiends you'll get the idea. I have already implemented most of the game logic, the only part I don't seem able to pull out is a way of checking if the game is playable (I.E. that there are at least 3 tiles in a row next to each other). I need this information so I can scramble the items into a playable set. Anyways, here is my Coroutine that checks if the board is playable:

```
IEnumerator isPlayable(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
        bool playable = false;
        TileObject first = null;
        TileObject next = null;
        int inLine = 0;
        foreach(GameObject GO in baseItems){
            if(playable)
                break;
            first = null;
            next = null;
            inLine = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                    if(visibleItems[i,j].name.Equals(GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name)){
                        if(first == null){
                            first = visibleItems[i,j];
                            if(inLine == 0)
                                inLine = 1;
                        } else if(next == null){
                            next = visibleItems[i,j];
                            if(isAdjacent(first, false, next)){
                                inLine++;
                                if(inLine >= 3){
                                    i = rows + 1;
                                    j = columns + 1;
                                    playable = true;
                                    break;
                                } else {
                                    first = next;
                                    next = null;
                                }
                            } else {
                                first = next;
                                next = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(playable)
                Debug.Log(GO.name + " Yes");
            else
                Debug.Log(GO.name + " No");
        }
}
```

As you can see I also call my "isAdjacent" function, which is as follows:

```
public  bool isAdjacent(TileObject tileObj, bool checkChosen = true, TileObject next = null){
    bool meetsRequirements = false;
    if(checkChosen){
        if(chosenItems != null && chosenItems.Count > 0){
            if(chosenItems.ToArray()[0].name.Equals(tileObj.name)){
                foreach(TileObject item in chosenItems){
                    meetsRequirements =     verifyDown(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                            verifyUp(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                            verifyLeft(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                            verifyRight(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                            verifyUpLeft(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                            verifyUpRight(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                            verifyDownLeft(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                            verifyDownRight(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow());
                }
            } else {
                meetsRequirements = false;
            }
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
    } else {
        meetsRequirements =     verifyRight(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                verifyDownRight(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                verifyDown(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                verifyDownLeft(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                verifyLeft(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                verifyUpLeft(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                verifyUp(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                verifyUpRight(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow());
    }
    return meetsRequirements;
}
```

I know the "isAdjacent" function works properly because it's the same I use to check if a chosen (clicked/tapped) item is nearby others of the same type. The "baseItems" array contains the GameObjects (which have the TileObject Script attatched) on which every in-game item are based. TileObject contains it's own name and they have their column and row number as well (used for the isAdjacent function). I'm pretty sure the problem with my logic is in the "isPlayable" Coroutine, but I can't tell why. Basically it needs to check if 3 of a kind (for example "blue item") are in a row (in any direction as long as they're adjacent), but it will sometimes display "Yes" when it's not a playable game or "No" when it is. It's not always that happens, but it does happen. Can someone help me? Hope I could accurately explain myself.

Edit: As an example I add this image:

[As you can see, green should have said "Yes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tEgN.png)

[In this other case, Blue should've said "No" and go all the way to "Yellow" to say "Yes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5f3H.png)

Comment: This might give you a push in the right direction: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48869/3-in-a-row-or-more-logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but just in case, here's my solution:

```
IEnumerator isPlayable(){
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
//      StartCoroutine(ClearConsole());
        string debugString = "";
        string debugLine = "En Linea: ";
        bool playable = false;
        // First tile to be compared
        TileObject first = null;
        // Next tile to be compared
        TileObject next = null;
        // Last tile in the 2D Array, used to determine if a loop should end or restart
        TileObject last = null;
        // Previous tile that was compared, saves the first tile after a next one was determined to be adjacent, this is to prevent cicled and false Trues
        TileObject previous = null;
        // Determines how many tiles are in line in the visible 2D Array
        int inLine = 0;
        foreach(GameObject GO in baseItems){
            if(playable)
                break;
            debugString = debugString + GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name + ": \n";
//          Debug.Log(GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name);
            last = getLastInArray(GO.name);
            previous = null;
            first = null;
            next = null;
            inLine = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
//              Debug.Log("i: " + i);
                for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
//                  Debug.Log("j: " + j);
                    if(visibleItems[i,j].name.Equals(GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name)){//GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name
                        if(first == null){
                            first = visibleItems[i,j];
                            if(inLine == 0)
                                inLine = 1;
                        } 
                        for(int a = 0; a < rows; a++){
//                          Debug.Log("a: " + a);
                            for(int b = 0; b < columns; b++){
//                              Debug.Log("b: " + b);
                                if(visibleItems[a,b].name.Equals(GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name)){
                                    if(visibleItems[a,b].Equals(first)){
                                        continue;
                                    } else {
                                        if(next == null){
                                            next = visibleItems[a,b];
                                            if(next.Equals(previous)){
                                                continue;
                                            } else {
                                                debugString = debugString + "Es " + first.name + "(" + first.getRow() + "," + first.getColumn() + ") adyacente a ";
                                                debugString = debugString + next.name + "(" + next.getRow() + "," + next.getColumn() + ")?: ";
                                                if(isAdjacent(first, false, next)){
                                                    debugString = debugString + " Si\n";
                                                    previous = first;
                                                    first = next;
                                                    next = null;
                                                    a = i;
                                                    b = j;
//                                                  Debug.Log("Es Adyacente");
                                                    inLine++;
                                                    if(inLine >= 3){
//                                                      Debug.Log("Es mayor igual a 3");
//                                                      Debug.Log(debugString);
                                                        debugLine = debugLine + inLine;
//                                                      Debug.Log(debugLine);
                                                        a = rows + 1;
                                                        b = columns + 1;
                                                        i = a;
                                                        j = b;
                                                        playable = true;
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                } else {
//                                                  Debug.Log("No es adyacente");
                                                    debugString = debugString + " No\n";
//                                                      Debug.Log(debugString);
                                                    if(next.Equals(last)){
//                                                      Debug.Log("Next es el ultimo");
                                                        previous = null;
                                                        first = null;
                                                        next = null;
                                                        inLine = 0;
                                                        break;
    //                                                      Debug.Log("i: " + i);
    //                                                      Debug.Log("j: " + j);
                                                    } else {
//                                                      Debug.Log("Next no es el ultimo");
                                                        next = null;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!playable){
                debugLine = "En Linea: ";
                debugLine = debugLine + inLine.ToString();
//              Debug.Log(debugString);
//              Debug.Log(debugLine);
                debugString = "";
                debugLine = "En Linea: ";
            }
//          if(playable)
//              Debug.Log(GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name + " Yes"); //GO.name
//          else
//              Debug.Log(GO.gameObject.GetComponent<TileObject>().name + " No"); //GO.name
        }
        if(!playable){
//          Debug.Log("No es Jugable");
            allowGame = false;
        } else {
//          Debug.Log("Es jugable");
            allowGame = true;
        }

        if(allowGame){
            if(!CandyCrushMain.Script.getStart()){
                CandyCrushMain.Script.gameStart();
                CandyCrushMain.Script.setEndTime();
            }
        }
    }
```

To check adjacency:

```
public  bool isAdjacent(TileObject tileObj, bool checkChosen = true, TileObject next = null){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(checkChosen){
            if(chosenItems != null && chosenItems.Count > 0){
                if(chosenItems.ToArray()[0].name.Equals(tileObj.name)){
                    foreach(TileObject item in chosenItems){
                        meetsRequirements =     verifyDown(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                                verifyUp(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                                verifyLeft(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                                verifyRight(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                                verifyUpLeft(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                                verifyUpRight(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                                verifyDownLeft(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                                verifyDownRight(item.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), item.getRow(), tileObj.getRow());
                    }
                } else {
                    meetsRequirements = false;
                }
            } else {
                meetsRequirements = false;
            }
        } else {
            meetsRequirements =     verifyRight(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                    verifyDownRight(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                    verifyDown(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
//                                  verifyDownLeft(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                    verifyLeft(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                    verifyUpLeft(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                    verifyUp(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow()) || 
                                    verifyUpRight(next.getColumn(), tileObj.getColumn(), next.getRow(), tileObj.getRow());
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }
```

And to verify in each direction:

```
public bool verifyDown(int column, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(column == x){
            if(y == 0){
                meetsRequirements =  false;
            } else if((y - row) == 1){
                meetsRequirements = true;
            } else {
                meetsRequirements = false;
            }
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }

    public bool verifyUp(int column, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(column == x){
            if(y >= rows - 1){
                meetsRequirements = false;
            } else if((row - y) == 1){
                meetsRequirements = true;
            } else {
                meetsRequirements = false;
            }
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }

    public bool verifyLeft(int column, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(row == y){
            if(x == 0){
                meetsRequirements = false;
            } else if((x - column) == 1){
                meetsRequirements = true;
            } else {
                meetsRequirements = false;
            }
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }

    public bool verifyRight(int column, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(row == y){
            if(x == columns - 1){
                meetsRequirements = false;
            } else if((column - x) == 1){
                meetsRequirements = true;
            } else {
                meetsRequirements = false;
            }
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }

    public bool verifyUpLeft(int column, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(y > rows -1 || x == 0){
            meetsRequirements = false;
        } else if((row - y) == 1 && (x - column) == 1){
            meetsRequirements = true;
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }

    public bool verifyUpRight(int column, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(y >= rows - 1 || x == columns - 1){
            meetsRequirements = false;
        } else if((row - y) == 1 && (column - x) == 1){
            meetsRequirements = true;
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }

    public bool verifyDownLeft(int columna, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(y == 0 || x == 0){
            meetsRequirements = false;
        } else if((y - row) == 1 && (x - columna) == 1){
            meetsRequirements  = true;
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }

    public bool verifyDownRight(int column, int x, int row, int y){
        bool meetsRequirements = false;
        if(y == 0 || x == columns - 1){
            meetsRequirements = false;
        } else if((y - row) == 1 && (column - x) == 1){
            meetsRequirements  = true;
        } else {
            meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        return meetsRequirements;
    }
```